# Github Actions Google Palm API No module named 'google.protobuf'

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, google-generativeai, palm-api

Im getting the following error when my Github actions tries to install `google-generativeai` for the Palm API. I tried adding `pip install protobuf` explicitly in the github actions yaml, added it in requirements.txt, and in my setup.py. Nothing works.

```
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.17/x64/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py:127: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
tests/test_adapt_decorator.py:6: in <module>
    from .model import GPT4, Claude
tests/model.py:8: in <module>
    import google.generativeai as palm
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.17/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google_generativeai-0.1.0-py3.9.egg/google/generativeai/__init__.py:69: in <module>
    from google.generativeai import types
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.17/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google_generativeai-0.1.0-py3.9.egg/google/generativeai/types/__init__.py:17: in <module>
    from google.generativeai.types.discuss_types import *
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.17/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google_generativeai-0.1.0-py3.9.egg/google/generativeai/types/discuss_types.py:21: in <module>
    import google.ai.generativelanguage as glm
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.17/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google_ai_generativelanguage-0.2.0-py3.9.egg/google/ai/generativelanguage/__init__.py:21: in <module>
    from google.ai.generativelanguage_v1beta2.services.discuss_service.async_client import (
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.17/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google_ai_generativelanguage-0.2.0-py3.9.egg/google/ai/generativelanguage_v1beta2/__init__.py:21: in <module>
    from .services.discuss_service import DiscussServiceAsyncClient, DiscussServiceClient
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.17/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google_ai_generativelanguage-0.2.0-py3.9.egg/google/ai/generativelanguage_v1beta2/services/discuss_service/__init__.py:16: in <module>
    from .async_client import DiscussServiceAsyncClient
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.17/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google_ai_generativelanguage-0.2.0-py3.9.egg/google/ai/generativelanguage_v1beta2/services/discuss_service/async_client.py:31: in <module>
    from google.api_core import exceptions as core_exceptions
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.17/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google_api_core-2.12.0.dev0-py3.9.egg/google/api_core/exceptions.py:29: in <module>
    from google.rpc import error_details_pb2
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.17/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/googleapis_common_protos-1.59.1-py3.9.egg/google/rpc/error_details_pb2.py:20: in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.protobuf'
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have hit a temporary issue. Try this again, and if it's still not working, [drop us a bug](https://goo.gle/palm-py-bug).